# Why does the mesh current equal for Thevenin's Equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, mesh-analysis

[image: Mesh Analysis]

[image]

The question wants us to find the thevenin's equivalent of this circuit. Vth is across R. The 5ohms and 6A was transformed into a series voltage and resistance.

The answer shows that the first loop is : -20 + 3i + Vth + 5i -30 = 0

The Above Loop is 2i - 10 - Vth = 0

My question is why does both mesh share the same current i, shouldn't they have their own respective currents i1 and i2 . Eg,  -20 + 3i1 + Vth + 5i1 -30 = 0 and 2i2 - 10 - Vth = 0

Comment: To be able to find the Vth voltage you need to disconnect the R resistor from the circuit and then you can find Vth in a circuit without R resistor. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/345594/calculating-thevenins-circuit-using-kcl-or-node-analysis/345620#345620

Comment: I did that already. Just wondering why the two mesh have the same current

Comment: Because now you have only one path for a current to flow (series circuit).  \$-20V+I_13Ω+I_12Ω-10V+I_16Ω-30V = 0\$

Comment: I've updated the diagram. But the solution shows that the 2ohms parallel to (3+5) ohms. shouldn't they have different currents?

Comment: How many closed-loop paths for a current to flow do you see in this circuit? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iazl1.png  Notice that R is a open circuit.

Comment: 1 loop. But why is the calculation for resistance different? 2ohms parallel to 3+5 ohms. Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: 2ohm parllel to (3+5) if  there is an actual source instead of just a notation (vth) and if you are confused by equation written on book , just add both equation and vth term gets cancelled and you got equation of just 1loop , while your equation work when you calculate thevenin resistance because now you have to replace vth by a source voltage and then 2ohm parllel to (3+8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

To find \$V_{TH}\$ voltage you need to disconnect the "load" resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyarVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And fins the \$V_{TH}\$ voltage.

But to be able to find \$R_{TH}\$. The Thevenin's equivalent resistance we need to short's all the voltage sources and open all the circuit current sources.
So, for your circuit it will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f38EdC.png)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much sir